# Display correctly array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I am using this function to return all available image size as array.

```
function king_image_size() {
  $image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
    foreach ($image_sizes as $tax) {
     $image_sizes[$tax] = $tax;
    }
   return $image_sizes
 }
```

But this duplicates the return array. Output

```
array(18) { [0]=> string(9) "thumbnail" [1]=> string(6) "medium" [2]=> string(12) "medium_large" [3]=> string(5) "large" [4]=> string(9) "dhaka-por" [5]=> string(11) "dhaka-por-h" [6]=> string(15) "dhaka-landscape" [7]=> string(7) "dhaka-h" [8]=> string(8) "dhaka-sq" ["thumbnail"]=> string(9) "thumbnail" ["medium"]=> string(6) "medium" ["medium_large"]=> string(12) "medium_large" ["large"]=> string(5) "large" ["dhaka-por"]=> string(9) "dhaka-por" ["dhaka-por-h"]=> string(11) "dhaka-por-h" ["dhaka-landscape"]=> string(15) "dhaka-landscape" ["dhaka-h"]=> string(7) "dhaka-h" ["dhaka-sq"]=> string(8) "dhaka-sq" }
```

Anotherway that I found very common,

```
function king_image_size() {
  $image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
  return $image_sizes;
}
```

Then I am getting 0,1,2,3... output in page builder. I need the function to work like

```
function king_image_size(){
  return array(
      'medium' => 'medium' ,
  );  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want an array that uses the values you got, as the keys as well …?

For that, you can simply use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), and just feed the value array in twice:

```
function king_image_size() {
  $image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

  return array_combine($image_sizes, $image_sizes);
}
```